# Convert filleoutputstream to a file java

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

Good Day

I am downloading a file using ftpclient, and is downloading successfully, I however have a problem converting this to a file

For example I am downloading a file called "helper.pdf" and I want to download the file as is to a local file called "helper.pdf"

Here is my code

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
  FileOutputStream fos = null;
  try
  {
     client.connect(Host);
     client.login(user_ftp, password_ftp);
     if (client.changeWorkingDirectory("workingdirectory"))
     {            
        fos = new FileOutputStream(Copy_file);
        if (client.retrieveFile(Copy_file, fos))
        {
           //System.out.println("FOS : "+fos.toString());
           //ObjectInputStream restore_file = new ObjectInputStream(fos);
        }            
        fos.close();
     }
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Downloaded", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }
  catch (Exception err)
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error downloading update file", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
```

So the question is how do I convert the FileOutputStream to a pdf or save it as a pdf file.

Comment: I think you have to create an instance of a file object.

Comment: I have never created an instance of a file object using fileoutputstream can you lead me in the right direction, all the examples I have seen on google have not helped.

Comment: See the answer of oe.elvik

Comment: You dont create a File with the FileOutputStream, but you pass it a File object and the FileOutputStream will fill it with content.

Comment: A `FileOutputStream` creates a file. Not a real question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File file = new File("c:/help.pdf");
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
if (client.retrieveFile("help.pdf", fos))
```

Comment: It has copied files to desired location, thank you for your help oe.elvik, the problem I have now is that the file is invalid or corrupt and I cannot open it. I would up vote you answer but I have insufficient points to do so.

Comment: are you shure the remote path was correct?

Comment: Yes would this code also work with zip or executable files? because this are the files that are refusing to open but are downloaded successfully.

Comment: client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); seemed to help fix issue with file download.